# To find the $a_3$ that minimizes the following definite integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

$$P_0(x)=1$$
$$P_1(x)=x$$
$$P_2(x)=2x^2-1$$
$$P_3(x)=4x^3-3x$$

$$R(x)=a_0P_0(x)+a_1P_1(x)+a_2P_2(x)+a_3P_3(x)$$
$f(x)$ is an arbitrary real function bounded on [-1,1].

How can I find the $a_3$ expressed by only $P_3(x)$ and $f(x)$ that minimize the following definite integral?
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left[f(x)-R(x)\right]^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I have known that if let $x=\cos\theta$ then $P_n(x)=\cos n\theta$, and I've calculated that$\int_{-1}^{1}R^2(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = a_0^2\pi+0.5a_1^2\pi+0.5a_2^2\pi+0.5a_3^2\pi$.

So I tried to expand the target integral and took its derivative to $a_3$, letting the result equal to $0$. Finally, I got this equation $a_3 = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)P_3(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$.
I still cannot get rid of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and the integral sign.

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you want to get rid of? ***This is*** your answer, as good as it gets.

Comment: Do you mean this is already the simplest form it can get?

Comment: Yes, pretty much so.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.